# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No enum constant

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a Role enum, like this:

```
public enum Role{
    admin('a'),
    member('m'),
    pending('p');
    char role;
    Role(char a) {
        this.role = a;
    }
    public char getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public static Role getByRole(char role) {
        return Arrays.stream(Role.values())
                .filter(Role -> Role.getRole() == role)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(Role.pending);
    }
}
```

To support conversion, I have created a class called RoleConverter:

```
@Converter
public class RoleConverter implements AttributeConverter<Role, Character> {
    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(Role Role) {
        return Role.getRole();
    }
    @Override
    public Role convertToEntityAttribute(Character dbData) {
        System.out.println(dbData);
        return Role.getByRole(dbData);
    }
}
```

And in my Target object I have added proper annotations:

```
    @Convert(converter = RoleConverter.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Role role;
```

Still it gives me error - **nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No enum constant com.mua.cse616.model.Role.2;**

*Using spring with h2 and jpa*

Comment: Seems like you have a row in your DB which has in the column the value 2 which obv is not present in the enum. Maybe you started out without the @Enumerated annotation thus JPA used the ordinal as the column value.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj i deleted the old db and everything is now working fine, can you post it as answer ?

Comment: I had the same problem.
Seems like you have a row in your DB which has in the column the value 1 which is not present in the enum. Thanks @RobertNiestroj

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like you have a row in your DB which has in the column the value 2 which obviously is not present in the enum. Maybe you started out without the `@Enumerated` annotation thus JPA used the ordinal as the column value.

Answer (score 2):

Your database contains an entry with role = 2.

Make sure that the entries in the database have the same values as in your Enum.