# how to get ENUM variable with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I have a model with an ENUM field defined as:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "CLASSIFICATION", length = 25)
private ClassificationEnum classification;
```

ClassificationEnum is defined as:

```
public enum ClassificationEnum {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3;
}
```

On repository class, when I try to get the model with Type2 classification,
I got the following error:

No enum constant [...].ClassificationEnum.2

The 2 is also the id of the class that
contains my enum (maybe it's not related), but I don't know why JPA is trying
to access my enum that way.

Comment: You don't post the complete Exception. Anyway, maybe it is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544982/invaliddataaccessapiusageexception-no-enum-constant

Comment: Yes.. It was that.. I was setting dummy values in another table and messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the enum class like this:

```
public enum ClassificationEnum {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3
}
```